# Google Sheets: function run by time-based trigger throws an error, while onEdit works

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, triggers

This `onEdit`-based function works:

```
 function onEdit(e) {
  
  const row = e.range.getRow();
  const col = e.range.getColumn();
  const as = e.source.getActiveSheet();
  const sheet_name = 'Sheet1'
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const sh = ss.getSheetByName(sheet_name);
    
  const values = sh.getRange('A2:A'+sh.getLastRow()).getValues().flat([1]);    
  
  if(as.getName() == sheet_name && col == 1 && row > 1){  

  var toCopy;
  values.forEach((el,index)=>{                           
    if (el!=''){
    toCopy = sh.getRange(index+2,1).getValue();
  }               
    if(el==''){
            sh.getRange(index+2,1).setValue(toCopy)
             }
                 })
}
}
```

But if i want to execute this function with time-based trigger, and change the function name from `function onEdit(e)` to `function myFunc(e)`, triggered execution fails with errors like:

`TypeError: Cannot read property 'getRow' of undefined at myFunc(Code:3:23)` - shown at failed Executions,

and

`TypeError: Cannot read property 'range' of undefined (line 3, file "Code")` - shown in the script editor.

Both errors deal with the second line, `const row = e.range.getRow();`.

How can i execute this function error-free with time-based trigger?

Comment: What is `e`?`````````````````​`````````````````

Comment: Ah, good question! Originally it was an event - now, with time-based execution, there is no event, correct?

Comment: Actually no. Well  partially yes. There is a event(the clock strikes at the time configured). But why do you expect a time event to have a `range` or `row`? It makes sense, when the event is a edit event(where the edit happens in a specific ``range``). So, what properties does a time event's `e` expose? Search the  official documentation to figure out.

Comment: Hmm, yes, but as i see, time based event have no objects, beside of times, like `hour`, `year`, and so on - https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/events#time-driven_events. Or do i look into wrong documentation? I'm a bit lost between time-driven objects and time-driven triggers... Do you maybe have a meaningful example how to use time-driven events in this context?

Comment: That's the doc. When a trigger  condition is satisfied, some information regarding the event is passed to the function typically called `e`- the event object. So, in this context, `e` (time driven event object) is pretty useless to you. Rewrite your function to not depend on the event object.

Comment: Is it still needed to create something like `function createTimeDrivenTriggers()` or trigger creation through app script backend is enough?

Comment: Backend is enough. Please take the time to read all pages in the official documentation about triggers. There are only 2-3 pages.

Answer (score 0):

With an edit by [sandman](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3290946/sandman) the working function looks like the following:

```
function fillMyRow() {
  
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const sh = ss.getSheetByName('Sheet1');
    
  const values = sh.getRange('A2:A'+sh.getLastRow()).getValues().flat([1]);

  var toCopy;
  values.forEach((el,index)=>{
    if (el != ''){
      toCopy = sh.getRange(index+2,1).getValue();
    } else {
      sh.getRange(index+2,1).setValue(toCopy)
    }
  })
}
```

It works manually and, executed by time-driven trigger, reachs expected results.